# train svm after hog and make vector redaction

Tags: opencv

i'm working on micro feature expression I can finally extract the features, 
by

```
HOGDescriptor mouth;
vector<float> descriptorsValues;
vector<Point> locations;
mouth.compute( img, descriptorsValues, Size(0,0), Size(0,0), locations);
```

i done it for each part of face

but I'd still need to feed into my own SVM

any help

also my feature vector is 3780 for each face part and they are 8 parts i think it's too long i need to make a reduction how can i do it